# Why is this component function returning null in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am following the tutorial "React JS Crash Course 2021" by Brad Traversy and am setting up a function that adds a task to the main app.

I keep getting this error :

```
Error: AddTask(...): Nothing was returned from render.
 This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

I don't know why this error is coming or what it means, so If someone could help me understand it and what part of the code is leading to it that would be appreciated

the code:

AddTask.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'


const AddTask = () =>{

const [text, setText] =useState('')
const [day, setDay] =useState('')
const [reminder, setReminder] =useState('false')



const onSubmit = (e) => {e.preventDefault()
if (!text){

    alert('Please enter task text')
    return
}

}

    return (
        <form className="add-form">
            <div className="form-control">
               <label>Task</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Add Task" 
               value={text} onChange ={
                (e) => setText(e.target.value)  
               }/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-control">
               <label>Day and time</label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Add day and time"
               value={day} onChange ={
                (e) => setDay(e.target.value)  
               }/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-control form-control-check">
               <label>Set Reminder</label>
               <input type="checkbox" 
               value={reminder} onChange ={
                (e) => setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)  
               }/>
            </div>

            <input type ="submit" value ="save task" className="btn btn-block"/>
                             
        </form>
    );
            }


export default AddTask
```

Main App

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";
import AddTask from "./components/AddTask";
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState ([{id:1, 
    text: 'Doctors Appointment',    
    day:'Feb 5 3:30 pm',
    reminder: true,
    },
    {id:2, 
        text: 'Meeting at School',    
        day:'Feb 9 2:30 pm',
        reminder: true,
        },
    {id:3, 
    text: 'Groceries',    
    day:'Feb 10 11:30 am',
    reminder: false,
            }]
               )
// 
const AddTask =(task) =>{
console.log(task)

}
// delete 
const deleteTask = (id) =>{
 setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !==id))
}
// Toggle Reminder
const toggleReminder = (id)=>{

setTasks(tasks.map((task)=>task.id===id ? {...task, reminder:!task.reminder}:task))
console.log(tasks)

}

  return (
    <div className="container">

   <Header />

  <AddTask onAdd={AddTask}/>

   {tasks.length > 0 ? <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete ={deleteTask} onToggle ={toggleReminder}/>:'no tasks to show'}



    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you reformat your code to be more readable? It's difficult to tell if `!text` is an early undefined return, or if it's really just part of the submit handler. Where is `onSubmit` even called, is this a complete code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared a function called `AddTask` in `App` component, which overwrites the `component AddTask` from the scope

Change its name to a lower case value and it will work

```
const addTask =(task) =>{
   console.log(task)

}
```

P.S. Javascript does automatic semicolon insertion and sometimes it can sometimes lead to unexpected results. Make sure you add semicolon after every statement to be safe